# Overlayer pushing away side navigation

Tags: html, css, screen, overlay

So I'm creating an single page website with a dot navigation at the side. I have a picture as background on the first section, because the website exists out of 5 section where you can scroll downwards.

The black screen is pushing away my right navigation downwards, i used z-index but thats only the makes sure that the navigation is displayed on top. margin and padding also on 0. I want the black screen with 50% opacity but that isn't working either.

What I need is a black screen with 50% opacity on top of my background picture covering the whole section without pushing away other elements.

```css
.back{
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 110%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 position: sticky;
 z-index: -1;
 background-size: cover;
}

#section1{
 background-image: url("../Content website/background.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 50;
}

/* Dot navigation */

.dotstyle-scaleup{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 3%;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li{
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 80px 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup .current1{
 background-color: #54a59f;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 80px 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: -2.5px;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
      <body>

     

        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Landings -->
            <div class="section" id="section1" data-anchor="page1">
              <div class="back"></div>
              <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
                <ul>
                  <li class="current1"><a href="#page1"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#page2"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#page3"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#page4"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#page5"></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can i know the reason why you changed the answer :) is there any issue with mine ? you are free to choose what you want, but i simply want if there is issue with mine ;)

Comment: Oh I thought I could choose more then one, both are good answers. but I still choose the second one because working with pseudo elements is new for me, and I don't want copy paste code blindly.

Comment: ah no, but it's ok if you choose the other since there is no issue with mine ;) simply pay attention to z-index so the navigation stay always on top

Comment: Thanks, z -index is 999 :), good to see that this community is so active in helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes you need to make:

- Add `position:relative` to your section container.
- Position your back in fixed position in your section with `position:fixed` and use the `top,left,bottom,right as 0` so it stretches over the entire length of your section.

```css
.back {
  background-color: black;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  opacity:0.5;
  position: fixed;
}

#section1 {
  position:relative;
  background-image: url("../Content website/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 50;
}


/* Dot navigation */

.dotstyle-scaleup {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup .current1 {
  background-color: #54a59f;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -2.5px;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Landings -->
  <div class="section" id="section1" data-anchor="page1">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
      <ul>
        <li class="current1">
          <a href="#page1"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page2"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page3"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page4"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page5"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: so you can remove widith/height also display :block ;) and change fixed to absolute :)

Comment: i advice you to avoid doing thing fast as your first attempt may contain incoherant things and you may get downvotes before you update your answer ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, I did mention the changes but didn't really modify them but just updated I guess.

Comment: also position relative is not necessary for fixed position of inner element .. only mandatory for absolute position

Comment: Slow and steady wins the race ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif But I'd suggest using it as it will be helpful for aligning further elements present inside the section container, but yeah it won't be necessary for position:fixed.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError haha true